# Parse Cloud Code function get deviceToken By username

Tags: javascript, session, parse-platform, parse-cloud-code

I am kinda new to the whole cloud code and I am having a bit of trouble fetching some data.
So what I basically want is a function that by giving it a '`username`' that is located in the Parse.User database, it will return the user's `objectId` which I will then use to locate the user's session in the `Parse.Session`, from there I will get the installationId which I will then use in the `Parse.Installation` to get the device token.

- **Note:** I have written a function that keeps only 1 session active per user.
- **My issue:** 
  The Query of Parse.Session has a result which only contains 3 objects, and the installationId is not included,therefor I can not find out what is the installation id and then use it to search the Parse.Installation to get the device token.

**input example:**

```
Input: 
{"from":"user1",
"msg":"hello",
"title":"Whatever title",
"to":"user2"}
```

Here is the existing code I currently have which doesn't work.

```
Parse.Cloud.define('gcm', function(request,response){

   var username = request.params.to;
   console.log("usr "+username);
   var userQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.User);
   userQuery.equalTo('username', username);
   userQuery.find({
    success: function(results){
     var objectId = results[0].id;
     console.log("obj id "+objectId);
     var user = new Parse.User();

   //Set your id to desired user object id
     user.id = objectId;


     var sessionQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Object.extend('Session'));
     sessionQuery.include(user);
     sessionQuery.find({
         success: function(results1){
         console.log("result classname type: "+typeof(results1[0]));

         var installId = results1[0].installationId ; //here is the value which I want from the result, but the object is type of _Session which does not have installationId.
         console.log("inst id "+installId);
         var InstallationQuery = new Parse.Query(Parse.Installation);
         InstallationQuery.equalTo('installationId',installId);
         InstallationQuery.find({
              success: function(results2){
                   var deviceToken = results2[0].get("deviceToken");
                   console.log("token "+deviceToken);
                   Parse.Cloud.httpRequest({
            method: "POST",
            url: " https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm/send",
            headers: {'Authorization' : 'key=AIzaSyDj4ISkLW7CzAQEQEhTsq3JYZK5OP8tSzY',
            'Content-Type' : 'application/json'},
                        body: { 
                "data": 
                {
                        "title": request.params.title,
                        "msg": request.params.msg
                },
                "to" : deviceToken
                  },
            success: function(httpResponse) {
                response.success("Message Sent!");
                        console.log(httpResponse.text);
                },
                error: function(httpResponse) {
                response.error("Error, Something went wrong.");
                        console.log("error 4: " + httpResponse.status);
                }
        });

              },
              error: function(error) {
              //error
              console.log("error 3: " + error);
              }
              });

         },
         error: function(error) {
         //error
          console.log("error 2: " + error);
         }
         });
     },
     error: function(error) {
     //error
     console.log("error 1: " + error);
    }
  });


});
```

Comment: Where is this cloud function triggered? In the app?

Comment: @Ralphilius The function is triggered when you click a certain button (just like any chat app). It runs the function with the parameters from the user's input.

Comment: For Android, you can use `getInstallationId` method to get current `InstallationId` on that device. There should be a similar method for iOS too. Then you can pass that value to cloud functions.